# Find items is SSRS by Id

Tags: reportingservices-2005

How do you find items in SSRS by ID?  I tried to use the id returned by another find result, a new guid to string and small random string all of which return the same error:

> The ID field has a value that is not valid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidElementException: The ID field has a value that is not valid.

Here is the code:

```
var request = new FindItemsRequest
        {
            Conditions = new[] { new SearchCondition { Name = "ID", Value = "test"} },
            Folder = "/"
        };
        return _ssrsService
            .FindItems(request)
            .Items
```

I'm using SSRS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this can't be done through the SSRS service.  Ended up finding all objects then using LINQ to filter down to the ID I need.

Answer (score 1):

The MS documentation on the [FindItems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.finditems(v=sql.90).aspx) method says:

> Applications that use FindItems typically accept user input for specific properties and property values. **The searchable properties are Name, Description, CreatedBy, CreationDate, ModifiedBy, and ModifiedDate.** The items that are returned are only those for which a user has Read Properties permission.